# Create search query

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I have a table named `Customers` with columns `FirstName, LastName, Email`

Let's pretend I have the customer:   John | Williams | johnW1234@gmail.com

Now how do I have to create my query so that if I search for:

```
"williams"       =>  match
"will john"      =>  Match
"will john 55"   =>  NO match
"will 1234"      =>  match
```

my query right now looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `Customers` WHERE `FirstName` LIKE _search_ OR `LastName` LIKE _search__
```

But if someone where to look for "will john" then my query will return no matches

Comment: What is `_search_` ? you didn't define what you want to find - examples are good but they can't replace a definition!

Comment: `_search_` is whatever the customer is looking for. It might be "williams" or "will john"... I want to write a query where it enables me to search for a customer just like you where to search for a contact on your phone for example

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what Tono's after.

Comment: the question title does not convince me though. feel free to change it to something more appropriate though!

Comment: It seems to me that your looking for a conditional search - if one thing is true, check the next thing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to do something like that:

```
select * from Customers where 
(FirstName like concat('%','john', '%') and LastName like concat('%','smith', '%'))
or
(LastName like concat('%','john', '%') and FirstName like concat('%','smith', '%'))
```

The parts: `john` and `smith` (in the query) are the different parts of the search term which is exploded by spaces and modified to lowercase (you can do it either in the code or in the DB).

Link to **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a110/2)**

Answer (score 1):

I think this works:

```
select * from Customers
where (_search_ regexp '^[^ ]+ [^ ]+$' or _search_ regexp '^[^ ]+$')
and (LastName like concat(substring_index(_search_, ' ',  1), '%'))
or FirstName like concat(substring_index(_search_, ' ',  -1), '%')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic sql can help you

```
 EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE FirstName LIKE ' ||
 _search_ || ' OR LastName LIKE ' || _search__ || ';';
```

"_ search _" should be converted to text (explicitly or not).

Of course, quotation waiting for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Crudely...

```
SET @string = 'John|Williams|johnW1234@gmail.com';

SELECT IF(@string LIKE "%will%",IF(@string LIKE "%john%",IF(@string LIKE "%55%",1,0),0),0)x;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 0 |
+---+

SELECT IF(@string LIKE "%will%",IF(@string LIKE "%john%",IF(@string LIKE "%12%",1,0),0),0)x;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```